# Is the multimodal as in multimodal machine learning the same as that as in multimodal distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, terminology, multimodality

The multimodal distribution is a distribution with multiple modes as shown below.

[image]

It reminds me of the [multimodal machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_learning) where multimodal implies multiple types of information, just like that in multimedia, thus I wonder if multimedia machine learning or multimedia deep learning would be more appropriate?

Does the multimodal machine learning have some connections with the multimodal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're unrelated. So-called multimodal machine learning operates on multiple input *modalities*. That is, input signals of different types (e.g. auditory and visual input). Multimodal distributions have probability density/mass functions with multiple *modes* (i.e. peaks). The existence of multiple input modalities doesn't imply anything about multiple modes in the input distribution, or any other distribution.